# I get the critical error "Invalid instance in App.root"?

Tags: python, exception, kivy

I get the error:

```
[CRITICAL] App.root must be an _instance_ of Widget
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/nurum/PycharmProjects/Mango/main.py", line 15, in <module>
 MyApp().run()
File "C:\Users\nurum\anaconda3\envs\Mango\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 835, in run
 raise Exception('Invalid instance in App.root')
Exception: Invalid instance in App.root
```

I don't actually understand where is the problem.
On the Kivy documentation, I've checked the source code for the kivy.app but still I don't understand how to fix this.
Here is the link:
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/_modules/kivy/app.html

The similar questions on StackOverflow did not help as the people code is different from mine :/

My code is:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
return MyGrid
```

to:

```
return MyGrid()
```

The first returns a class object, the second returns a `Widget`.

Comment: Thank you John... And the video tutorial had the () added. It was totally my own mistake..

Answer (score 0):

Parenthesis are missing after return MyGrid